# Domain access to web application - Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I am using a Tomcat server that can be accessed via `https://<IP>:8443/webappname` (works for all web apps)

This tomcat server is also configured to be accessed by domain like: `https://mydomain123.com/webappname`

However, not all webapps are accesible. How to make a new web application in the webapps folder accessible like the above (domain).

Comment: Without sharing more information about

 - Is there a proxy that enables you to run the tomcat apps on the default ssl port?
 - What proxy do you use? apache httpd? nginx? lighttpd? something else?
 - How is the proxy connection set up between apache httpd(?) and the tomcat server? ajp? proxy_http?
 - How what apps do not work? what tells you that they do not work? 

there be barely anyone who can help you.

Please remember: the quality of the answer is strongly influenced by the quality of the question.

Comment: from what is see, there is a "stunnel" proxy software installed in the server

Comment: Isn't this configured in tomcat?

Comment: stunnel is an SSL wrapper, not a proxy (as far as I know). Can you please check what kind of daemon occupies port 443?

Comment: This depends on your tomcat configuration. You can make it listen to different ports via the connector tags in the server.xml config.

Comment: i have checked the server and its using httpd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Apache (httpd) is running in front of Tomcat, it is most likely using `mod_proxy` to forward requests for some webapps to Tomcat. Since it works for some webapps but not others, try looking into the Apache config files (usually under `/etc/apache2` in Linux) for lines starting with `ProxyPass`, similar to this:

```
ProxyPass /example ajp://localhost:8009/example
ProxyPassReverse /example ajp://localhost:8009/example
```

There should be two lines like this for each webapp accessible through Apache. Just copy those lines and change the name of the webapp ("example" above) to proxy other apps.

If you don't find any `ProxyPass` line in the Apache config files, it may be using a different module, like `mod_jk`.

Comment: Mostly on the default installation path:  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation, but your sys-admin or devops should know this.

Comment: Yes I know the path of installation, what I mean which config file to look for?

Comment: The main config file should be called `httpd.conf`.

Comment: if its using mod_jk where can I find the config file?

Comment: Config for mod_jk should be in the same directory or a subdir, but based on your httpd.conf, it doesn't look like it's loading the mod_jk module. Maybe it's using some other proxying module. I'm afraid I can't help you.